# Vue test utils with nuxt - committing a mutation

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I am using vue test utils with nuxt, I have a standard mutation

```
 this.$store.commit(
        'users/UPDATE_NAME',
        this.username
      )
```

In my .spec I am trying to access this mutation but I get the error

***TypeError: Cannot read property 'commit' of undefined***

I have tried mocking it too

```
   it("It should commit the change name mutation", () => {
    
      const wrapper = shallowMount(ChangeName, {
        mocks: {
          $store: {
            // what goes here
          }
```

but don't know how to setup the wrapper so it has access to the mutation inside the module 'users'

```
  this.$store.commit('users/UPDATE_NAME',this.username)
```

How do I setup the .spec to have access to this mutation?